# Eclipse no longer makes import suggestions in quickfixes

Tags: java, eclipse

eclipse isn't making import suggestions anymore. I don't know why it stopped. Here is an example.
[image]

Comment: Does it do it for every class, or just with some libraries, your own classes, or JRE classes?

Comment: Do you have more than one BufferedImage in the build path?

Comment: It's not just with BufferedImage that's just an example. it seems to do it with ALL imports except for packages that are in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check to see if it is enabled to automatically do it.  Go to `Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist` and make sure `Enable auto activation` is checked.

If that doesn't fix anything, you can try to manually get it to show up by pressing `CTRL + SPACE`.

You should also check `Content Assist > Advanced` and make sure that at the very least `Java Proposals` is checked.

Comment: I tried all of it but it still displays no import suggestions. even when i CTRL + SPACE

Answer (score 1):

Reopen eclipse.Thats the only case i make it work again each time it happen.Cleaning up project doesnt help.I found this really annoying.Bud im sorry to tell that i have no idea why this happens. Seems like a bug in eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=75582

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when you have some brackets missing in your source code, and the suggestion system just cannot figure out how to do suggestions anymore.